# FDT:Flex and cannot access local file

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flexbuilder, flex3, fdt

I am using FDT for Flex development and when I compile, and it tries to access a flv file, I get the error "cannot access local file". This is obviously a security sandbox thing.

Now I tried adding crossdomain.xml to the root and it still makes the same error. I know somehow I need to add to my project use-network=false, but i cant for the life of me work out where the flex compiler additional arguments area is. I know in eclipse how to do it, but with the slightly modified FDT, i havent got a clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling 'FDT Security' throws up a similar discussion [here](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=2552)... might be related to your problem?